# Positive X and Y movement of a ball acting different than Negative X and Y movement

Tags: java, swing

In my implementation of the update method (where I handle movement), movement induced by positive and negative velocity are handled in the same way, but when the golf ball moves either north or east, the movement is different than the southern and western movement.

Pasted below is my update method, and after looking at it for hours, I just don't understand what is making the movement like it is.

```
public void update() {
    double deceleration = 0.9; // Deceleration factor

    // Check if the ball is moving
    if (vx != 0 || vy != 0) {
        isMoving = true;
        updateCount++; // Increment the counter
    }

    // Apply deceleration to both components
    vx *= deceleration;
    vy *= deceleration;

    // Update position using the decelerated velocity components
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
    // System.out.println("vX: "+vx+" vY: "+vy);

    // Set velocity to zero when vx or vy is too small to matter
    if (Math.abs(vx) < 0.000001) {
        vx = 0;
    }
    if (Math.abs(vy) < 0.000001) {
        vy = 0;
    }
    

    // Border coordinates and dimensions
    int borderX = 100; // Update these values to match the actual border coordinates and dimensions
    int borderY = 100;
    int borderWidth = 800;
    int borderHeight = 600;

    // Bounce off the borders
    if (x + RADIUS >= borderX + borderWidth || x - RADIUS <= borderX) {
        vx *= -1; // Reverse horizontal velocity
        x = Math.min(x, borderX + borderWidth - RADIUS);
        x = Math.max(x, borderX + RADIUS);
    }
    if (y + RADIUS >= borderY + borderHeight || y - RADIUS <= borderY) {
        vy *= -1; // Reverse vertical velocity
        y = Math.min(y, borderY + borderHeight - RADIUS);
        y = Math.max(y, borderY + RADIUS);
    }

    // If the ball has stopped moving and was previously moving, log the update count
    if (vx == 0 && vy == 0 && isMoving) {
        System.out.println("Ball stopped moving after "+updateCount+" updates. ");
        isMoving = false; // Reset the moving stae
        updateCount = 0; // Reset the counter
    }
}
```

I tried rewriting the movement handling code several times, checking over the deltaX and Y values, etc.

Comment: I can't speak for everybody, but I personally think that your question would be much easier to answer if you created and posted a decent [mre] code post with the question. Please look at the link and then consider creating and posting one of these with your question. This often involves a bit of work on your part, but it is work that is well worth it as it helps you to understand and isolate the problem, a process often leads you to a solution yourself, or failing that, allows for you to post a better code and question which helps you get a better and quicker answer from us.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that demonstrates the problem.  That means it must be compilable and executable.  Also take the [tour] and read [ask] so you may better participate on this site.  Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: There must be an *echo* here ;)

Comment: Ships in the night!

Comment: Are `vx`, `vy` indeed `double`? Because with `int` rounding negative numbers then result may differ. `(int)(7*0.9) == 6`.

Comment: Rounding may be an issue, as well as the fact that your ball position may not be the middle of the ball but the upper left corner. Depends how you paint it, which is not shown.

Answer (score -1):

You need to handle the movement induced by positive and negative velocity differently for north and east compared to south and west direction. and may be that is the reason that you are looking for.

```
    public void update() {
    double deceleration = 0.9; // Deceleration factor

    // Check if the ball is moving
    if (vx != 0 || vy != 0) {
        isMoving = true;
        updateCount++; // Increment the counter
    }

    // Apply deceleration to both components
    vx *= deceleration;
    vy *= deceleration;

    // Update position using the decelerated velocity components
    x += vx;
    y += vy;
    // System.out.println("vX: "+vx+" vY: "+vy);

    // Set velocity to zero when vx or vy is too small to matter
    if (Math.abs(vx) < 0.000001) {
        vx = 0;
    }
    if (Math.abs(vy) < 0.000001) {
        vy = 0;
    }
    

    // Border coordinates and dimensions
    int borderX = 100; // Update these values to match the actual border coordinates and dimensions
    int borderY = 100;
    int borderWidth = 800;
    int borderHeight = 600;

    // Bounce off the borders
    if (x + RADIUS >= borderX + borderWidth || x - RADIUS <= borderX) {
        if (vx > 0) {
            vx *= -1; // Reverse horizontal velocity
        }
        x = Math.min(x, borderX + borderWidth - RADIUS);
        x = Math.max(x, borderX + RADIUS);
    }
    if (y + RADIUS >= borderY + borderHeight || y - RADIUS <= borderY) {
        if (vy > 0) {
            vy *= -1; // Reverse vertical velocity
        }
        y = Math.min(y, borderY + borderHeight - RADIUS);
        y = Math.max(y, borderY + RADIUS);
    }

    // If the ball has stopped moving and was previously moving, log the update count
    if (vx == 0 && vy == 0 && isMoving) {
        System.out.println("Ball stopped moving after "+updateCount+" updates. ");
        isMoving = false; // Reset the moving state
        updateCount = 0; // Reset the counter
    }
}
```